# simple multiplication or operator issue

Tags: c++

I am trying to run this simple code. But I am missing something. I tried to look at operator overloading. Could someone explain what I am missing here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){

    std::vector < std::vector<double> > tm;
    std::vector<int> dfg;

    // Creating a simple matrix
    double ta1[]={0.5,0.5,0};
    std::vector <double> tv1 (ta1, ta1+3);
    tm.push_back(tv1);

    double ta2[]={0.5,0,0};
    std::vector <double> tv2 (ta2, ta2+3);
    tm.push_back(tv2);

    double ta3[]={0,0.5,0};
    std::vector <double> tv3 (ta3, ta3+3);
    tm.push_back(tv3);

    double d_load =0.5;

    // doing some simple calculations 

    for (int destinationID = 1; destinationID <= tm.size(); destinationID++){
         float randomNum = ((double) rand())/((double) RAND_MAX);
         if (randomNum <= d_load * tm[destinationID - 1])
             dfg.push_back(destinationID);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error.

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘d_load * tm.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = std::vector<double>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<double> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = std::vector<double>&, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int](((long unsigned int)(destinationID + -0x00000000000000001)))’
```

Comment: `tm[destinationID - 1]` is a vector. You can't multiply a vector by a double. Moreover, you're comparing this product with a `float`, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks I shall check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tm` is a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, thus effectively it is a **2**-dimensional dynamic array of `double`.  This means that to access the individual `double` elements in `tm`, you would use something like this:

`double value = tm[destinationID - 1][theValueIndex];`

It is the `[theValueIndex]` part of the loop that you're missing.

Since we don't know your exact intentions on how you want to traverse the array, I leave it to you to fill in this gap.

Answer (score 1):

The following line is invalid:

```
d_load * tm[destinationID - 1]
```

Since `tm` is a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, The elements of `tm` are `std::vector<double>`, not `double`. If you want to multiply each number or check that each number matches the condition, you have to iterate the element you're getting out of `tm[]`